# Switch function had a strange return with `scanf`

Tags: c++, c

I was working on a program with a simple switch function, so far it has always worked for me.
But this time I have a problem with the `scanf` function before the switch.
I honestly don't understand where the error may be.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main () {
int utente;
while(1) {
printf("Benvenuto, premere:\n");
printf("1) AZIONE 1\n");
printf("2) AZIONE 2\n");
printf("3) AZIONE 3\n");
printf("4) AZIONE 4\n");
printf("5) AZIONE 5\n");
printf("6) AZIONE 6\n");
scanf ("%d\n",&utente);
switch(utente) {
        case 1: {
                printf("AZIONE 1\n");
                break;
        }

        case 2:{
                printf("AZIONE 2\n");
                break;
        }
        case 3: {
                printf("AZIONE 3\n");
                break;
        }
        case 4: {
                printf("AZIONE 4\n");
                break;
        }
        case 5: {
                printf("AZIONE 5\n");
                break;
        }
return 0
```

I can't understand the return. After the scanf he asks me for another input to enter the switch. otherwise it does not enter. In the case of while, I repeat the cycle with a delay output on the houses. And it's an extremely easy program. I don't know if it is a problem of the switch or the scanf.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A whitepace character (space, newline, tab, etc) in scanf's format string means it'll ignore *any* number of whitespaces in the input. So when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (which sends a newline character), it'll be ignored regardless of how many you send. In order to terminate this directive, you have to input a non-whitepace character.

From [C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5):

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never
>   fails.

That's what you observe here.

The solution is to remove the `\n` from the format string.

Note that scanf is generally error prone for user inputs and is hard to use correctly (see what happens if you input a non integer, such as `a`, to your program).

See [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 0):

because of new line '\n', in the scanf statement, after format specifier(%d), you were facing trouble.